# Force modify values

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to make a simple thing, maybe someone can help,

I want to check the value which entered by user if it already exist in table, and if not i want Access to force change the name of book.
here is my code to check if exist:

```
Private Sub Item_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  If Volume = DLookup("[Volume]", "[Books]", "[Book_name]='" & [Item] & "'") Then
      x = MsgBox("Book already exist", vbOKOnly)
  End If
End Sub
```

Now, what should I write to force user to change the name of book (without deletting the text)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cancel the Update by setting the Cancel variable to true. The sample at the end of the [Msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211264%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for `BeforeUpdate` shows an example as well.

```
Private Sub Item_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  If Volume = DLookup("[Volume]", "[Books]", "[Book_name]='" & [Item] & "'") Then
      x = MsgBox("Book already exist", vbOKOnly)
      Cancel = True 'do not update give the user another try
  End If
End Sub
```